# 'Path used multiple times' when migrating to Google Cloud Endpoints v2

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

Our team received a mail from Google saying we should move to Google Cloud Endpoints V2 because v1 is now deprecated. The migration guide is quite simple. But after redeploying my AppEngine (python) app, we got this new error:
`ApiConfigurationError: POST path "XXX" used multiple times, in classes YYY and ZZZ`

That's true we use the same path in the `@endpoints.method` annotation but they are under different `@endpoints.api` so I don't see any problem.

Did Someone else experienced this? Do I really need to rename the paths?

Comment: This is a bug. If you don't mind filing a bug at the [Github repo](https://github.com/cloudendpoints/endpoints-python) it would be great!

Comment: done ;-) https://github.com/cloudendpoints/endpoints-python/issues/74